# Should SO/SF/SU support stoplivinginthepast movement against internet explorer 6

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, internet-explorer-6

Jeff Atwood [said](http://search.twitter.com/search?q=&ands=ie6&from=codinghorror) something about "ie6 and the sites" on twitter recently, then I thought maybe SO/SF/SU may support the movement "[stop living in the past](http://www.stoplivinginthepast.com/)" and show a nice banner to warn ie6 users...

Will it be aggressive?

Edit: only a warning (huge or small) pointing out that ie has newer versions like 7 or 8 and they are better for everyone...

Answer (score 4):

Declined: if you are using IE6 you are being punished already.

Plus, there are enough little things that will be wonky or broken on today's web under IE6 that I don't think a warning banner matters.

Comment: "Using vi is not a sin but penance"

Answer (score 2):

While I agree with the sentiment there is a real problem with this movement. A lot of people browsing the web at work have to adhere to company IT policy and that often includes sticking with IE6. Now while there'll be fewer programmers and sys admins with that restriction there might well be more Super User users and having an aggressive "stop using IE6" policy would put them off.

Comment: As a side note to this, one of our suppliers provides an application that doesn't work beyond IE6...

Comment: @Rowland What the f... :)

Comment: @Piotr That was my response too :)

Comment: there will be nothing bad for them, they only see the warning message and maybe they will criticize the policy again... and I don't think there are still a lot of companies like this...

Answer (score 1):

I think most past persons are in the industry: they're not allowed to upgrade or use another browser. Is there a site stat about the amount of old browser usage?

**Edit:** How would you feel if one day your browser wouldn't be supported by the site any more? I don't know the WAP(?) version but they could just use that interface as it is a much simpler UI.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that specific message is it's way to user-unfriendly.  It's like the sites that pop up a huge banner telling me how getting Firefox will save the souls of my children or something like that.

If the site really does have some limitations on IE6, what's wrong with *This site will preform better with a newer version of Internet Explorer.  It's a free upgrade [link].*

If a site doesn't work with IE6 this is a failure on the part of the programmer, not the user: don't blame the user!

Comment: Yeah, sure. It's everyone's fault but M$...

Comment: but will it *perform* better?

Answer (score 0):

Very cool.
To all opponents; it's not about not supporting but about warning!